# Using ui-router and controllerAs can I simplify the adding of services?

Tags: angularjs

I have this code:

```
   var home = {
        name: 'home',
        template: '<div data-ui-view></div>',
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'app/access/partials/home.html',
        controller: ['accessService', function (accessService: IAccessService) {
                this.ac = accessService;
            }],
        controllerAs: 'home'
    };

    var homeAccess = {
        name: 'home.access',
        url: 'Access',
        templateUrl: 'app/access/partials/webapi.html',
        controller: ['accessService', function (accessService: IAccessService) {
                this.ac = accessService;
            }],
        controllerAs: 'homeAccess',
        resolve: {
            abc: ['accessService', function (accessService) {
                return accessService.getAbc();
            }],
            def: ['accessService', function (accessService) {
                return accessService.getDef();
            }]
        }
    };
```

Now that I am using controllerAs is there a way that I can simplify this code so as to eliminate adding the accessService into both of the controllers and into the two parts of the resolve? Also if I did this then how could I get to the access service inside the home.html and also the webapi.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably a few different ways, just thinking out loud here.

Your `home` state is the parent of `home.access` and it uses a `ui-view` to show the child state. As such the template for the child state can reference the controller in the parent state. This is just the regular inheritance of $scope in Angular views, although it's much cleaner b/c you are using the controllerAs syntax.

For example, your views might end up looking like this:

```
<home-template>
  <p>{{home.someValue}}</p>

  <!-- included by the ui-view -->
  <home-access-template>
    <p>{{homeAccess.anotherValue}}
    <!-- this works b/c home is on the parent scope -->
    <p>{{home.someOtherValue}}</p>
  </home-access-template>

<home-template>
```

So **if it makes sense in your scenario**, you only need to inject your `accessService` into the parent controller. The child views will use the service through methods of the parent controller.

A similar thing can also be done with the resolves: by declaring them on the parent state, they are available to the child states. **This is more useful when there are many child states for a given parent**.